# When building world devices what wall voltages should you expect?

Tags: power, mains

I want to build a dishwasher safe toaster (more details in other questions), So Simplicity of design is a must. Fortunately toasters are among the simplest of electrical devices consisting of nothing more than a switch and a couple really big resistors called heating elements (one on each side of the bread). I figure I can ignore 440/277 systems and focus just on systems that have a 110 or 220 volt standard. Unfortunately there seems to be significant variation within each range. For example I have seen 110v, 115v, 117v, and 120v secondaries on transformers targeting 110v devices before we get to line loss. Similarly I have seen 220v, 230v, and 240v transformers. When building a device for the world market what are the highest and lowest voltages you would reasonably expect to see from the wall in each of these ranges?

Comment: wikipedia has an excellent page listing almost all countries voltages, and from there you can find a lot of their voltage tolerances.

Comment: 230VAC/50Hz should be the most common world-wide, but there's hardly any standard. [Check this](http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plug-voltage-by-country/). General-purpose AC/DC converters cover a wide span, but they are trickier to design. For that, I'd recommend checking out the various switches made by [Power Integrations](http://www.power.com/).

Answer (score 1):

10% less than 100V is 90V, and 10% more than 240V is 264V. This is why 86V to 264V is such a common range, and the one commonly accepted by devices that connect to line power.

Comment: so what would the low voltage in the 220v range and the high voltage in the 110v range?

Answer (score 1):

Ignacio is correct that the steady-state voltage allowance is usually +10% / -10% of nominal voltage.

However, to be safe under all conditions (i.e. not catch fire) **your appliance must also be able to withstand transient overvoltages**, such as those caused by lightning strikes on the distribution network. See [another answer of mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87937/apple-power-supply-thick-ac-cable-thin-dc-cable-why/87946#87946).

> Your thick mains power cord is insulated to withstand mains voltage. In your country, that's 110 VAC; in my country it's 230 VAC. On top of that, the insulation must withstand transient voltage spikes ("surges") - AS1660.3 specifies a multi-core flexible cable must withstand a 3,000V AC hi-pot test for five minutes, so the insulation must be thick enough to withstand 3,000V RMS or 4,200 V peak.

Which is to say, your toaster might only take 230 VAC in normal operation, but might need to withstand up to 4,200V to pass appliance testing.

For this purpose, "blows a fuse and doesn't work any more" counts as "withstanding the test". The aim is to make sure that the toaster fails in a safe manner, i.e. doesn't catch fire.

In Australia, some other relevant standards are AS 1768 *Lightning Protection* and AS 4070 *Protection of low voltage installations*. I'm not at work and don't have access to my Standards Australia subscription, so I can't investigate any further.

Comment: I knew about the +-10%, And the lightning information is useful, but what I am looking for it the range of official or measured wall voltages. By the way I always enjoy reading what you write.